# Case Statements sum for different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question on how to write this out. The total points cannot exceed 1 for a person (Jack) and below here, shows a total of 2. How would I write a case statement (or better options) where I would be able to make sure that only count certain actions totaled up to 1 or just a total in 1 in general.

```
Person  Date    Action  Value
Jack    1/1/16  Eat     0.5
Jack    1/2/16  Sleep   0.5
Jack    1/3/16  Walk    0.5
Jack    1/4/16  Sit     0.5
```

So for example, the total for Jack when I aggregate it elsewhere (excel) would equal to 1 for the value and not 2.

I'm currently trying out temp tables with row number seeing if I meet certain requirements I will make 2 of those 0.5 = 0.

**I would only want the values to be 0.5 or 1.**

Comment: can you please tag the rdms you are using (sql server, mysql, ...)?

Comment: Count the total number of rows and divide 1 with total number of rows? Not sure what you're asking really? Please provide what you've tried so far, and expected result? Are the values always 0.5 for every row?

Comment: It sounds like you want to conditionally count certain Actions, (like count "eat" towards the sum but not "sleep").  Is this what you mean by "be able to make sure that only count certain actions totaled up to 1".  Your grammar is making it hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Where does the 0.5 come from?  What does it mean?  Why can't it be more than 1?  Can it not be more than one when aggregated across all 4 rows?  What sort of aggregation are you doing in Excel?  ***Please*** provide the context.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select Person, Date, Action,
       Action / sum(action) over (partition by person) as p_action
from t;
```

It will normalize the values for each name so they all add up to 1.

Comment: shouldn't it be partition by?

Comment: Maybe OP doesn't want normalizing for aggregates below 1? Like for single row with action value 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for some conditional sum idea; here I compile some approaches:

```
WITH Sample (Person, Date, Action, Value) AS
(
     SELECT 'Jack', '1/1/16', 'Eat'  , 0.5 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Jack', '1/2/16', 'Sleep', 0.5 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Jack', '1/3/16', 'Walk' , 0.5 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Jack', '1/4/16', 'Sit'  , 0.5
)
SELECT      Person, 

            -- plain sum
            SUM(Value) PlainSum,

            -- 1.0 will be the maximum value for this expression
            CASE    WHEN    SUM(Value) > 1.00
                    THEN    1.00
                    ELSE    SUM(Value)
            END     MaxOne,

            -- here we can define different values for each action type
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN    Action = 'Eat'   THEN 0.25
                    WHEN    Action = 'Sleep' THEN 0.00
                    WHEN    Action = 'Walk'  THEN 0.25
                    ELSE    Value
                END)    CustomSum
FROM        Sample
GROUP BY    Person
```